# Scala Type Parameter with Either

Tags: scala, specs2

```
class OptionLikeMatcher[F[_], T, U](typeName: String, toOption: F[T] => Option[U]) extends Matcher[F[T]] { ... }
case class RightMatcher[T]() extends OptionLikeMatcher[({type l[a]=Either[_, a]})#l, T, T]("Right", (_:Either[Any, T]).right.toOption)
case class LeftMatcher[T]() extends OptionLikeMatcher[({type l[a]=Either[a, _]})#l, T, T]("Left", (_:Either[T, Any]).left.toOption)
```

Can some one explain what are they trying to achieve here with the type parameters?
What type does the `toOption: F[T] => Option[U]` parameter have when used for `RightMatcher` and `LeftMatcher`?

Its from Scala Specs2 library.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what is the question.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first address the most complicated type constructor here:

```
({type l[a]=Either[_, a]})#l
```

is the original way to encode *type lambdas*. It could be written more succinctly as either

```
Either[_, ?]
```

with kind-projector, or as

```
[X] =>> Either[_, X]
```

in Scala 3. It basically just selects the right parameter of `Either` as the relevant one, and replaces the left parameter by a wildcard.

---

Now, the three type parameters of `OptionLikeMatcher` are:

- `F[_]` - the type constructor for the thing that's being matched; It is expected to behave "somewhat similarly" to `Option`, i.e. there should be some way to get an `Option` out of it.
- `T` is the type that is plugged into the `F` type constructor; Together `F[T]` gives the type of what's being matched.
- `U` can be thought as a "slightly perturbed" version of `T`; It captures basically the same information as `T`, but it allows for some controlled sloppiness when transforming an `F[T]` into an `Option[U]` (otherwise, if one required `F[T] => Option[T]`, that would practically be the same as asking for quite a rigid structure called *natural transformation* `F ~> Option`, which might be too restrictive in this case).

---

Putting it all together gives for `RightMatcher`:

- `F[A] = Either[_, A]` - i.e. pick right parameter of `Either`, ignore left parameter
- The `T` from the `OptionLikeMatcher` is bound to `T` from `RightMatcher`
- The `U` from the `OptionLikeMatcher` is also bound to `T` from `RightMatcher`, i.e. the possibility to "slightly perturb" `T` is not used here, both `T` and `U` from `OptionLikeMatcher` are instantiated by the same type.

Thus, the `toOption` in `RightMatcher` has the type `Either[_, T] => Option[T]`. The `(_:Either[Any, T]).right.toOption` conforms to `Either[_, T] => Option[T]`, because the `Any` appears in a covariant position within `Either`, and `Either[Any, T]` appears in a contravariant position within the function type, so that `Either[Any, T] => Option[T]` is a subtype of `Either[_, T] => Option[T]`, because its input type is strictly more permissive, and it can be used everywhere an `Either[_, T] => Option[T]` is needed.

---

All that being said, I couldn't find any applications of `F` that were not of shape `F[T]` (neither in `OptionLikeMatcher`, nor in `OptionLikeChekedMatcher`), so it seems that they are splitting up the input type into a type constructor `F` and a type parameter `T`, only to use them as an indivisible unit `F[T]` later on. Maybe this was left over after a refactoring from some more complicated construct.

Comment: > All that being said, I couldn't find any applications of F that were not of shape F[T] 
That's correct Andrey, this is total over-engineering! This will be simplified in the next major version of specs2. On the bright side that gave you the opportunity for a good StackOverflow answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

> What type does the `toOption: F[T] => Option[U]` parameter have when used for `RightMatcher` and `LeftMatcher`

Perhaps a concrete drill exercise would help. Let's consider `RightMatcher[Int]()` where we instantiate type parameter `T` to `Int`. This gives us

```
F = ({type l[a]=Either[_, a]})#l
T = Int
U = T = Int
```

and plugging the above type instantiations into

```
toOption: F[T] => Option[U]
```

we get

```
toOption: (({type l[a]=Either[_, a]})#l)[Int] => Option[Int]
```

which simplifies to

```
toOption: Either[_, Int] => Option[Int]
```

Let's do another drill for `LeftMatcher[String]()`. We have

```
F = ({type l[a]=Either[a, _]})#l
T = String
U = T = String
```

and plugging the above type instantiations into

```
toOption: F[T] => Option[U]
```

we get

```
toOption: (({type l[a]=Either[a, _]})#l)[String] => Option[String]
```

which simplifies to

```
toOption: Either[String, _] => Option[String]
```